# Why I'm getting this error?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have in stored procedure in SQL Server that use function and return RESULT a decimal.

In C# I need to get it but I get an error :

> "INVALLD CastEXCEPTION was unhandeld by user code" "an exception of
>   type 'system.invaildCastException' occured...'

My C# code:

```
decimal? val = null;      

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
con.Open();

using (con)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spSetOrderDetails", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter tvpParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDetailsItemsTVP", dt);
    tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

    // this part of code return the SUM
    SqlParameter returnParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@RESULT", SqlDbType.Decimal);
    returnParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    val = (decimal)cmd.Parameters["@RESULT"].Value;--HERE I GET THE EXCEPTION
}

con.Close();
return (decimal)val;
```

Comment: cmd.Parameters["@RESULT"].Value could be NULL and you can't cast NULL to non-nullable decimal.

Comment: You can't The parameter with the direction ReturnValue is the value of the RETURN statemen in T-SQL and that value can only be an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast the parameter with ParameterDirection.ReturnValue to a datatype that is not an integer.

[The RETURN statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) in T-SQL can only return integer values.

However, if you are absolutely certain that your Stored Procedure ends always with something like RETURN xxx then you could

```
val = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.Parameters["@RESULT"].Value);
```

Comment: Does SQL server allow to call .Value over dbulll column ?

Comment: A parameter with Direction = ReturnValue contains the value of the T-SQL RETURN statement, no columns involved here

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = cmd.Parameters["@RESULT"];

if(res != null && res.Value != null && res.Value != DbNull.value){
val = Convert.ToDecimal(res.Value);
}
else
val = defaultvalue;
```

This code will check if it's null or equal to dbnull.value. It will only cast if it's not null or dbnull.value. In case of null (or dbnull.value) it will simply set the value to defaultvalue for decimal.

Comment: This code check dbnull.value, if database have null value for the column it will check both null and dbnull.value otherwise set the default value;

Comment: convert.ToDecimal will not make exception if it's fail it's simply return zero (from another answer). this code will cast only those which are not null otherwise setting default value.

Comment: What is the purpose of checking if the _parameter object_ (not its value) is null or dbnull? The parameter has been added in the parameter collection just two lines before so we are pretty sure that it exists. The problem is a Invalid Cast Exception not a Null Reference Exception

Comment: @Steve Actually I see this kind of thing first time. I mainly use MySQL.